# how to set switch inside item list of toolbar in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to set switch in item list beside title in toolbar. Is there is any way to set the switch beside the title in item list, as I have shown in Image. Can any one help me to find out the solution.

Thank you.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/extend"
    android:title="@string/clear_once_a_week"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below solution might work for you. So give it a try and go through the defined steps.

- Step 1: Create a layout with a switch (for ex.switch_layout):

  ```
  RelativeLayout

  -> Add a Switch/SwitchCompat inside your parent layout
  ```
- Step 2: In your activity override onCreateOptionsMenu as below:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.id_of_your_menu_item);
      item.setActionView(R.layout.switch_layout); // Set your custom layout here

      SwitchCompat mSwitch = item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_switch);
      mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    });
    return true;
  }
  ```

> Or you can set an action view in your menu item directly instead of
> adding it programmatically. Choose the best way according to your requirement.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
/>
```

Comment: can you please provide me a code in java I don't know kotlin I am new to kotlin

Comment: yes I have tried your code the custom menu it appears on the top of the toolbar but I want the switch in list item. as example in toolbar 3dots clicked the list appears ,in that list I want the switch as I have shown in the image

Comment: I think it would do the same thing as per my understanding. Can you please run the above code and share a screenshot if possible?